# why GoogleMock reports not match with exact same arguments value?

Tags: c++, googlemock

The pure virtual class

```cpp
class ConfigGetter {
 public:
  virtual const std::string Get(const char *name,
                                const char *default_value) const = 0;
};
```

The mock

```cpp
class MockConfigGetter : public engine::ConfigGetter {
 public:
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD2(Get, const std::string(const char *, const char *));
};
```

Test case

```cpp
TEST(ConfigTest, NormalString) {
  NiceMock<MockConfigGetter> getter;
  EXPECT_CALL(getter, Get("SERVER_LISTEN_PORT", ""))
      .WillRepeatedly(Return("80"));
  // Pass
  ASSERT_EQ("80", getter.Get("SERVER_LISTEN_PORT", ""));
  // GetNewConfig internal call getter->Get("SERVER_LISTEN_PORT", "")
  auto f = engine::GetNewConfig(&getter);
  ASSERT_NE(f, nullptr);
  // Failure
  ASSERT_EQ(80, f->listen_port);
}
```

And good mock reports:

```
Unexpected mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: Get(0x556fb6ea4860 pointing to "SERVER_LISTEN_PORT", 0x556fb6ea4843 pointing to "")
          Returns: ""
Google Mock tried the following 1 expectation, but it didn't match:

/home/phillip/projects/engine-test/src/config/config-test.cpp:26: EXPECT_CALL(getter, Get("SERVER_LISTEN_PORT", ""))...
  Expected arg #0: is equal to 0x556fb6ea2878 pointing to "SERVER_LISTEN_PORT"
           Actual: 0x556fb6ea4860 pointing to "SERVER_LISTEN_PORT"
  Expected arg #1: is equal to 0x556fb6ea27bc pointing to ""
           Actual: 0x556fb6ea4843 pointing to ""
         Expected: to be called any number of times
           Actual: called twice - satisfied and active
```

arg0 and arg1 is exactly the same as EXPECT_CALL. I don't know why the second call fail to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because gmock compares values of arguments, i.e. pointers. To compare strings you need to add corresponding matchers, i.e.

```
EXPECT_CALL(getter, Get(StrEq("SERVER_LISTEN_PORT"), StrEq("")))
      .WillRepeatedly(Return("80"));
```